# How to replace all commas without a space, but not commas with a space?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, preg-match

Like, I could have done this if the second part of this question's title didn't exist:

```
$string = 'Hello,this is my string.';
$replacedstring = str_replace(',', ', ', $string);
```

But what if the user did correctly format the sentence, as in `Hello, this is my string.`. Then that would result in it becoming `Hello,  this is my string.`, which I do not want.

So, how would I do that using `preg_replace` and similar regex functions in PHP?

Comment: how about allowing the user to format it anyway way they like.

Comment: @Dagon no, I specifically need to format it that way

Comment: tying to fix all potential issues with user content never works

Comment: @Dagon well I'm trying as hard as I can.

Comment: Beware that if someone submits code such as "," your replacement will cause this to become ", " and may break their code sample.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$replaced_string = preg_replace("/,([^\s])/", ", $1", $str);
```

I would use this.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$ret = preg_replace('/(?<=\S,)(?=\S)/', ' ', $string);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you (I upvoted you), and I seriously don't know.

Comment: This solution works and I agree that assertions (lookbehind and lookahead) are the cleanest way to check for the pattern you need. (Whether they are faster than capture patterns is another matter.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
str_replace(array(', ', ','), ', ', $string);
```

Is redundant because replace `,` with `,` but probably is more efficient that a regex or any other algorithm for texts not very large

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'Hello,this is my string, sir.';
$pattern = '/,([^ ])/'; # every comma that is followed by anything but space
$replacement = ', ';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```